# How to get metadata out of AWS Cognito JWT to use it for the MongoDB Stitch Metadata Fields?

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito, custom-authentication, mongodb-stitch

I am using AWS Cognito as the custom authentication for my MongoDB Stitch app. I can successfully retrieve the JWT from AWS Cognito and login to MongoDB Stitch. I would like to store attributes in the JWT. I need help on how to get the JWT path to the metadata to put in MongoDB's Users -> Providers -> Metadata Fields.

[image]

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No. Stuck on this last step. I successfully implemented the authentication. I just don’t yet know how to store the metadata. Do check out and upvote [https://mongodb.canny.io/mongodb-stitch/p/store-jwt-metadata](https://mongodb.canny.io/mongodb-stitch/p/store-jwt-metadata)

Comment: I already upvoted and commented :) Jump onto the slack mongodb community there is a dedicated channel for stitch with some stitch gurus on there from MongoDB - i'm Adam Holt on there - https://join.slack.com/t/mongo-db/shared_invite/enQtMjk0NjQ5OTE2ODY5LWM2NWU1NDZhNzg2NWJmZDMwMzFlNjkwMTEzMzQ5YmU0NzE5NzM0OTllMWE3ODJmZDk3Y2YyMDg1NTg1NDkxYzg

Answer (score 0):

Feature has been added link to MongoDB Stitch. Here is the documentation to [Configure Custom User Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/users/configure-custom-user-data/index.html).